# c# regex nearest character

Tags: c#, regex

Im using a regex expression on a string and i have the issue that there is nothing to the left of the string which doesnt reaccur in the string multiple times.

```
">something">tofind</a>
```

this part:

```
</a>
```

is unique in the string but the

```
">
```

part to the left is NOT

how can i make an expression take the first "> to the left of the (to be matched) value and not the first one from the start of the string

```
\">(.*)</a>
```

doesnt work properly due to that and gives me ">tofind and rightfully so.

any solution? i would like the solution to my problem be inside the expression and not additional code. due to my inabillty to hardcode a fix for every special problem i might have with strings.

thanks alot!

code processing the string

```
                    var regex = new Regex(regexstring);

                    var matches = regex.Matches(line);

                    foreach (var singleuser in matches.Cast<Match>().ToList())
                    {
                        allusernames.Add(singleuser.Groups[1].Value);
                    }
```

Comment: As a side note, [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) is an awesome way to process HTML in C#!

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Is `">something">tofind</a>` the literal thing to process and you are looking for the text  `something` within that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following..

```
\">([^>]*)</a>
```

Explanation:

- `\">` match literal `\">`
- `([^>]*)` match all characters other than `>` (`[^>]` being negated set)
- `</a>` match literal `</a>`

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%22%3e(%5b%5e%3e%5d*)%3c%2fa%3e&i=%22%3esomething%22%3etofind%3c%2fa%3e)

Comment: my hero! can you briefly explain what you have done?

Comment: Good explanation, it was what the user needed.